# Изменить фон StatusBar

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер.
Каким образом возможно изменить фон statusBar в приложении? что-то на подобии этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался в стиль добавить

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dcolor</item>
```

Но это мне не помогло.
Буду благодарен за любую информацию!

Answer (score 4):

Можно менять цвет statusBar только начиная с Андроид 5. Если используете AppCompat библиотеку, то вот так:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
</style>
```

Если без AppCompat, то так:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
</style>
```